# Wget 1.12 binary for Windows, can anybody find it?

Tags: command-line, download, web, wget, mirroring

I've been trying to find a Wget v1.12 binary for Windows as it [parses CSS](https://superuser.com/questions/55040/save-a-single-web-page-with-background-images-with-wget). No success. I successfully compiled for OS X but can't do the same for Windows. Is anybody else able to find or compile?

Comment: @mikael, check depiman's answer below, this question is answered

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any, even [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) did not upgrade its wget version yet.

This might not be surprising, as the windows/README file found in [wget 1.12 sources](ftp://ftp.ironie.org/ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/wget/wget-1.12.tar.gz) starts this way:

> NOTE: as of version 1.12, the building
>   of Wget on Windows using these
>   supplied Makefiles, is severely
>   broken. HOWEVER, it is currently
>   possible to build Wget on Windows
>   using the standard Unix-y "./configure
>   && make", under MinGW + MSYS, though
>   there are some rough edges when you go
>   beyond the basic build.
>
> We expect to support this method for
>   building Wget more fully in future
>   releases; the degree to which other
>   Windows build methods will be
>   supported is not currently clear, as
>   the cost of their maintenance has
>   grown significantly.

Furthermore, searching wget mailing list, [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-wget@gnu.org/msg00579.html) was stated soon before the release of wget 1.12:

> If I get it to build on Windows (any
>   method) before then, I'll include
>   those relevant changes in the sources,
>   too... but it may not include "frills"
>   like IDN/IRI support, or even
>   statically-linked builds. I think
>   "polished" Windows support will
>   probably have to wait until 1.12.1 -
>   even if we get nice builds going for
>   Windows wgets, there won't have been
>   sufficient time to *test* wget on
>   Windows, so the quality will be
>   dubious.

Answer (score 1):

http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

This mingw distribution includes a compiled binary of wget 1.12

The download is a .7z self-extracting achive..
so just open it up in 7zip and extract wget.exe..
no .dlls needed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the developers [question](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-wget@gnu.org/msg00579.html) if it will compile on Windows. :(

> I think "polished" Windows support will probably have to wait until 1.12.1 - even if we get nice builds going for Windows wgets, there won't have been sufficient time to _test_ wget on Windows, so the quality will be dubious.

Answer (score 0):

http://drop.io/GetGnuWin32

read the site well!