# Download a single web page (including images from CSS)

Tags: command-line, download, wget, web, mirroring

I want to download a single web page including everything needed to view the web page locally (this includes images linked in the css).

Example URL i want to download:

```
http://www.example.com/page1
```

The image are linked relatively in the css like this:

```
background: url(../img/example.jpg)
```

I have tried to download the page with Wget for Windows, but it doesn't download images from css or js files.

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off http://www.example.com/
```

The above solution from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/55040/save-a-single-web-page-with-background-images-with-wget) also doesn-t work.

I also tried [this method](https://gist.github.com/parkerl/1771976) which explains how to extract URLs from the css with grep to an txt file, but my txt file is empty when I try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save a single web page (with background images) with Wget](http://superuser.com/questions/55040/save-a-single-web-page-with-background-images-with-wget)

Comment: I don't want to download the whole page, it would take days

Comment: httrack is downloading the images yes and it is easier to set rules, but it is still downloading the whole page which takes forever. Maybe I need to set more rules. Bottom line is that I got the images needed for the css files. Thanks